# Calling other functions of a class inside a Promise in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, this, es6-promise

So, I have two methods in a class. Both returns a promise. The second function calls the first function from inside of the promise it returns.

```
module.exports = {
 funcA: () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       something ? resolve(something): reject('nope');
  });
 }

 funcB: () => {
    return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                const something = await this.funcA();
            } catch(err) {
                reject('error');
    }
 }
}
```

When I am trying to call funcB() from another class, like this:

```
let something = await someService.funcB();
```

I am getting:

```
TypeError: this.funcA() is not a function
```

Can you shed some light on why this is happening and how to solve this problem?

Comment: just stop using `new Promise` and all your problems will magically disappear ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one way to make it work is to create the function outside of the `module.exports` block to get a reference of each function. Then `this` keyword can be omitted

```
const funcA = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // code here
  });
};

const funcB = () => {
  return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        const something = await funcA();
        resolve(something);
    } catch(err) {
        reject('error');
    }
  })
};

module.exports = {
  funcA,
  funcB
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you need to do

```
module.exports = {
 funcA: function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       something ? resolve(something): reject('nope');
  });
 }

 funcB: function() {
    return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                const something = await this.funcA();
            } catch(err) {
                reject('error');
    }
 }
}
```

I've found using arrow functions inside objects as you've done breaks `this`, but you can fix it this way.